# printbibliography with only a part of references

Tags: beamer, bibliographies

I am making a presentation in LaTeX using `\mode<presentation>`, which gives me a slide-show format, which is exactly what I want to get. Unfortunately, using slides means that in my bibliography I can fit only 4 references per slide. When I use `\printbibliography` with tens of references I cannot fit them all on one slide.

Hence I was wondering- is there a way of printing references 1-4 on the first slide, then references 5-8 on the second etc.?

Comment: If you are using `beamer` `[allowframebreaks]` might be what you are looking for. Then `beamer` can simply distribute the contents on a frame that would run off-frame onto the next frames. If that does not help, please tell us more about your document setup (are you using `beamer`? are you using `biblatex`? how do you include the bibliography?). This is best done in a so-called MWE (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864), a short example file that starts with `\documentclass`, has the relevant bits of the preamble and a dummy `\begin{document}...\end{document}` environment.

Comment: Thanks, I am using beamer and [allowframebreakes] did the job exactly the way I wanted, cheers!